# ierate each row and pass the values of two columns to a query and append each result to the table

Tags: mysql, database, join, sql-update, subquery

I have a table with the structure below with name `table1`

```
sid  userid    date        result
1    169110   2020-01-03   (null)
2    178662   2020-01-06   (null)
3    165381   2020-01-07   (null)
5    368031   2020-01-08   (null)
7    163626   2020-01-09   (null)
```

Now I need to send each row values of `cft.userid` and `cft.date` to a mysql query (query is below) which gives the value of the result for each row

```
UPDATE collision_fact_table cft 
  SET cft.on_time_completion = (
 SELECT DISTINCT
        CONCAT(ROUND(NULLIF(SUM(facttable.compliant), 0) / NULLIF(SUM(facttable.Occurences), 0) * 100), '%') AS `Percentage Completed`
        FROM fd_dw.ComplianceFactTable facttable
WHERE  (CAST(facttable.`CourseModule_dueDateID` AS date) - cft.collision_date) <= 0
    AND facttable.UserLicenseInUsing = 1 
    AND (facttable.`CourseModule_dueDateID` > 0)
    AND facttable.UserId = cft.userid
    GROUP BY facttable.`UserID`);
```

For example, when i send first row values of userid 169110 and date value to the above query, i will get result as 69 and i need to update 69 to the `table1` like below

```
sid  userid    date        result
1    169110   2020-01-03   69
```

Similarly  it should iterate for all the rows and `table1` should get updated like below

```
sid  userid    date        result
1    169110   2020-01-03   69
2    178662   2020-01-06   55
3    165381   2020-01-07   64
5    368031   2020-01-08   48
7    163626   2020-01-09   56
```

But when i tried to execute the update query, its giving me error  `Unknown column 'cft.date' in field list`

Please anyone help me

Answer (score 0):

I think you basically want a correlated subquery:

```
update table1 t1
set result = (
    select cd.result
    from ...
    where 
        cd.ScheduleDateID <= t1.date
        and cd.CourseModuleComplete_DateID <= t1.date
        and cd.UserId = t1.userid
)
```

You don't give much details about the subquery itself. It is critical that it should return one row, and one row only:

- if it returns no rows, then the `result` of the corresponding row in `table1` will be set to `null` (regardless of its original value) - this might, or might not be what you want
- if it returns more than one row, then the query will error

Comment: Thanks for your reply!. Does only each row values will be passed into the subquery?

Comment: @Sai: yes, the subquery is executed for each and every row in `table1`, and update the corresponding `result`.

Comment: Hi..I have updated my subquery in the question. I am getting error ```Unknown column 'cft.collision_date' in 'field list```